# Mysql run count distinct inside another query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql query that returns an array of rows.  I need to get a count of distinct values from one column.
My query is dynamic, where multiple conditions evaluated by php change the WHERE clause, so I really want to do it all inside one query if possible to avoid duplicating every single dynamic condition.

Here is a simple version of what I would like to do --

If this represents a very simple version of my sql table:

```
Column1, Column2, Column3, Group, Active
   a   ,    b   ,    c   ,   1  ,  YES
   d   ,    e   ,    f,  ,   2  ,  YES
   g   ,    h   ,    i   ,   1  ,  YES
   j   ,    k   ,    l   ,   3  ,  NO
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
"SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, Group,
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Group) FROM 'table') AS totalGroups
 FROM 'table'
WHERE Active like 'YES';"
```

I want the result to be that I can report:

a) the total rows in the query

```
mysql_num_rows($result) should equal = 3
```

b) the total number of distinct groups

```
$phparray['totalgroups'] should equal = 2
(Right now, 'totalgroups' equals = 3)
```

(1) Can this be done? Currently, 'totalgroups' returns 3 instead of two.  Can I get it to use the same "Where" clause as the rest of the query?

In my actual code, which is much more complex, my count is returning 1,945 when I'm only wanting it to return 2. :)

(2) Is there a better way to do it?

I tried php's `array_unique()` and `array_count_values()`, but `array_unique()` does not work on multidimensional arrays, and I couldn't get `array_count_values()` to work correctly.

I looked at many other questions, but couldn't find one where someone was asking this particular question.
I reviewed the MYSQL manual RE subqueries, but it didn't address whether you could share the Where clause.

If you must have my actual code in order to answer this question (instead of the demo representation above), please let me know.  It's over two pages with all the php dynamic qualifiers, so I decided to write demo code for clarity's sake.

Comment: Sorry for what must be a confusing question.  I have been researching for hours, and cannot find an answer that works.  I tried COUNT(DISTINCT table.Group) AS totalGroups and it returns the correct value, but then only returns one row.  The other rows are not in the query.  I feel like I'm missing something simple ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to get a list of all the records on the table, along with on every line a count of the number of active rows and a count of the unique active groups?

If so then something like this:-

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, Group, ActiveDistinctGroups.ActiveCnt, ActiveGroups.ActiveCnt
FROM 'table' a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Group) AS ActiveCnt FROM 'table' WHERE Active like 'YES') AS ActiveDistinctGroups
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(Group) AS ActiveCnt FROM 'table' WHERE Active like 'YES') AS ActiveGroups
WHERE Active like 'YES'
```

If you really need to avoid the extra WHERE clauses:-

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, Group, ActiveDistinctGroups.ActiveCnt, ActiveGroups.ActiveCnt
FROM 'table' a
INNER JOIN (SELECT Active, COUNT(DISTINCT Group) AS ActiveCnt FROM 'table' GROUP BY Active) AS ActiveDistinctGroups ON a.Active = ActiveDistinctGroups.Active
INNER JOIN (SELECT ActiveCOUNT(Group) AS ActiveCnt FROM 'table' GROUP BY Active) AS ActiveGroups ON a.Active = ActiveGroups.Active
WHERE a.Active like 'YES'
```

Comment: Yes, I would like to return all records into an array, along with a count of the unique active groups.  

I can get the total number of groups by running mysql_num_rows on the result.  I really only want to put the "where" clause in once, at the bottom.  Does it have to go in each subquery or is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Edited to add a version where the check for active is only used once.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that next time I'm at my computer!

Comment: Thanks!  I worked your 2nd version into my original code, and it works.  Thanks for taking the time to dive into this.